# Storing visitors information using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter for my project and want to store all visitors information into database. I've a core controller named My_Controller and using this a bellow:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class My_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Tool_model');
        $this->Tool_model->save_visitor($this->get_visitor_data());
    }

    function get_visitor_data(){
        $src = $this->agent->is_referral()?explode('/',$this->agent->referrer()):NULL;

        $device = $this->agent->is_mobile() ? $this->agent->mobile() : "PC";

        $cur_link = uri_string() == NULL ? 'home' : end(explode('/',uri_string()));

        $data = array(
            'ip' => $this->input->ip_address(),
            'src' => $src[2],
            'page_link' => $cur_link,
            'browser' => $this->agent->browser(),
            'browser_ver' => $this->agent->version(),
            'os' => $this->agent->platform(),
            'device' => $device
        );

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Now I need to know that, is it a right way or there is another way to do the same thing more efficiently?

Thanks.

Comment: best way?It vary man to man.you doing one of them

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. There are too many ways to do that. But all of them are not the best. Do you have any suggestion to do that?

Comment: I said its vary to persons.1.You can keep one row at your db and update it each time when ppl visit- if you only need the visitor count.2.you can insert record each time visitors comes your site with ip,and other detail like visiting time. this way help you to know more details about your visit count .3.another way if same ip already visited update that row instead of inserting it. now you can pick which one best form your requirement

Comment: Extending `CI_Controller` class is one of the right way, I am not sure `hooks` may help on this too.